# Is it possible to implement ARSCNView in Custom Keyboard Extension?

Tags: swift, custom-keyboard

I'm facing out some problems after that I added, successfully, the ARSCNView to my Custom Keyboard Extension. The problem is that I set on the info.plist (both on the project both on the target) the "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" but when I'm installing the app or opening the camera the alert where I need to allow the camera for the use and for this reason the app is not doing what's expected.

Any help? There are some restriction on the usage of the Custom Keyboard Extension?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I thing No,  I was Already work on this and i cant find anything..

Comment: So sad ...I found also that extensions can’t access to camera usage